# Is there a way to correctly tag (PoS Tagging) the words which are forming a phrase together?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

I tried various means to correctly tag a bunch of words which form a phrase (especially Noun Phrase) but could not succeed.

Example: 'the', 'first', 'early','morning', 'sunbeams'

'early' and 'morning' are wrongly being tagged as 'Noun' where expected outcome should be: ('first', 'adverb'), ('early', 'adverb'), ('morning', 'adjective'), ('sunbeams', 'noun')

Could you please suggest a procedure to tag these words correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, did you try using NLTK?

Comment: NLTK is great. There's an easy function to do this in it, appropriately named nltk.word_tokenize()

Comment: I am looking for suggestion for PoS tagging while nltk.word_tokenize() breaks down a sentence into words or tokens. BTW, I even tried bigram HMM but no luck.

Comment: I don't agree with morning being an adjective, IMHO it's a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POS taggers normally use Hidden Markov Models. If your data is not tagged correctly with these methods, then either your tagger (selfmade?) is not suited for your input data or your training data is not adequate (too small, false annotations etc.). Various means I assume to be taggers from NLTK, spaCy, or tools from Stanford (https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/). These software packages will do the job in the quality of current research, so if it is still error-prone, you won't be able to fix it.
If you have a large cluster at hand, build your own tagger using n-grams with n > 3, if you like, but I doubt this will be any better than the modules named above.

Comment: Thanks, I think I should concentrate on the data part instead of playing around with PoS tagging techniques

Comment: maybe have a look whether you can get data from here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/miralium/wikis/PosTaggerTutorial.wiki  or from ntlk: nltk.corpus.treebank.tagged_sents(), or conll2000, but good training data is really scarce, since annotators want to be paid, so large data with annotations is really expensive...

Comment: Thank you so much..really appreciate